# strange compiling error saying 'no buildable Go source files'

Tags: go

Bascially, in client.go I import a package like this

```
pb "github.com/wilbyang/gotham-grpc/search"
```

when I try to run go run client.go, I get the error:

> no buildable Go source files in /Users/wilbyang/goPath/src/github.com/wilbyang/gotham-grpc/search".

My gopath is:

> "/Users/wilbyang/goPath/".

And I am sure dir `$GOPATH/src/github.com/wilbyang/gotham-grpc/search` exists and under that dir `search.pb.go` exists, generated by protoc and package being search. I really do not understand why and struggled with it for hours! Anyone would lead me out of this?

Comment: It could be a syntax error in your files.

Comment: What is the package name in the `search.pb.go` file?

Comment: the package name is 'search'

Comment: @David If you go to `$GOPATH/src/github.com/wilbyang/gotham-grpc/search` and do `go build` what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

`go run client.go` works when there is a `main` function inside `client.go`.